# Finding roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: diffie-hellman

Is there an efficient way (algorihtm) to compute the solutions of the congruence $x^n\equiv a \pmod p$?

- $n\in \mathbb{N}$
- $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$
- $p$ is a large prime number

**Note that:**

- By efficient I mean computationally efficient even when the given prime $p$ is appropriate for use in cryptographic protocols (hard to find discrete logarithm in $\mathbb{Z}_p$)
- We do not know the prime factors of $p-1$.

It’s easy to find one solution when $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$.

I think this should be as hard as finding a Discrete Logarithm or as Factoring. Any ideas ? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an extended but still **partial** attempt at an explicit solution.

Since $p$ is prime, [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) tells us that:

- $\forall z\in\mathbb Z_p, z^p\equiv z\pmod p$.
- $\forall z\in\mathbb Z_p^*, z^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$.

We settle some easy cases:

- If $n=0$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod p$, our equation $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$ is ill-defined.
- If $n>0$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod p$, the solution is $x\equiv0\pmod p$.
- If $n\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$ and $a\equiv 1\pmod p$, any $x\not\equiv0\pmod p$ is solution.
- If $n\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$, $a\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $a\not\equiv 1\pmod p$, there is no solution.
- If $n\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$, the solution is $x\equiv a\bmod p$.

In all the other cases, $x\equiv0\pmod p$ will not be a solution, and we can reduce $n$ modulo $p-1$ to obtain an equivalent equation. From then on, we will assume $1<n<p-1$, $a\not\equiv0\pmod p$, $x\not\equiv0\pmod p$, and proceed to solve our equation $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$.

As pointed out in the question, things are easy when $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$: the only solution is $x\equiv a^{n^{-1}\bmod(p-1)}\pmod p$. Proof: For the stated $x$, we have $x^n\equiv a^{(n^{-1}\bmod(p-1))·n}\pmod p$; thus $\exists k\in\mathbb N, x^n\equiv a^{1+k·(p-1)}\pmod p$; thus $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$; thus the stated $x$ is a solution of our equation. The function $z\mapsto z^n$ is thus a [surjective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective) over the finite set $\mathbb Z_p^*$, thus a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), thus there is no solution other than the stated one.

If $\gcd(n,p-1)\neq 1$, let it be $m$, with both $n/m$ and $(p-1)/m$ integers. We find $b$ such that $b^{n/m}\equiv a\bmod(p-1)$ by the above method; that is: $b=a^{(n/m)^{-1}\bmod(p-1)}\bmod p$. Solving $x^m\equiv b\pmod p$ is equivalent to our original equation.

By raising to the power $(p-1)/m$, we see that $x^m\equiv b\pmod p\implies 1\equiv b^{(p-1)/m}\pmod p$. Thus if $1\not\equiv b^{(p-1)/m}\pmod p$, which we can check, there is no solution.

This test is quite useful; for example when $p=71$, $n=55$, $a=2$, we have $m=5$, $(n/m)^{-1}\bmod(p-1)=51$, $b=3$, $b^{(p-1)/m}\bmod p=54$, thus no solution, and that's the case for most $a$. But for $a=20$ we get $b=45$, $b^{(p-1)/m}\bmod p=1$, and indeed there are $5$ solutions $\{18,19,24,32,49\}\pmod p$.

---

We can thus restrict to solving $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$ when $n$ divides $p-1$, $n>1$, and $a^{(p-1)/n}\equiv 1\pmod p$ (we have shown that any other $a$ leaves the equation without solution, except $a\equiv 0\pmod p$; and we have an efficient method to reduce to that case for any other $n$).

**That equation has exactly $n$ distinct solutions $\pmod p$**. Proof: by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), any polynomial of degree $n$ in the field $\mathbb Z_p$ has exactly $n$ roots, counted with multiplicity; applying that to $x^n-a$ we see that $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$ has at most $n$ solutions $\pmod p$; similarly there are at most $(p-1)/n$ solutions in $a$ to the equation $a^{(p-1)/n}\equiv 1\pmod p$; thus the function $z\mapsto z^n$ over the finite set $\mathbb Z_p^*$ maps at most $n$ elements to any element, and at most $(p-1)/n$ elements have a [preimage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage#Inverse_image); by a counting argument, every element with a preimage thus has exactly $n$ preimages.

It follows that we can not aim at finding *all* the solutions in time polynomial w.r.t. $\log p$ for arbitrary $n$: there are too many solutions when $n$ is big, e.g. $n=(p-1)/2$. We can still aim at finding *one* solution, or perhaps the smallest one.

When $(p-1)/n$ is small, there is an efficient and trivial probabilistic algorithm that finds a solution: pick a random $x$, and check if $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$, until a suitable $x$ is found; that is expected to require $(p-1)/n$ steps. By trying $x$ sequentially starting from $2$, we can find the smallest $x$.

If the exponent $n$ is even, we can change the unknown to $y\equiv x^{n/2}\pmod p$ and first solve $y^2=a\pmod p$, which is the well-studied problem of finding a [square root modulo a prime](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Modular_Square_Root). By applying this recursively, we can remove the powers of $2$ from the factorization of $n$. Assuming a polynomial-time algorithm finding a solution for any odd exponent $n$, our resulting algorithm would find a solution and work for any exponent, while remaining polynomial in $\log p$ after reduction of the exponent $n\pmod p$.

This is studied and generalized by [Adleman-Manders-Miller](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/AMM77.pdf), solving the problem in time polynomial w.r.t. $\log p$ for fixed $n$. Their algorithm is (at worse) linear w.r.t. $n$ (not $\log n$), and as an aside requires the factorization of $n$.

This might be improved by [Barreto-Voloch](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/roots.pdf), and perhaps these [two](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4877) [re-visitations](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.4801) of Adleman-Manders-Miller and Barreto-Voloch.

[To be continued. Feel free to improve this community wiki, e.g. by including a description of Adleman-Manders-Miller; I'll have no time to do that in the following week.]

An instance of the original problem with random exponent has a fair chance of being solvable with the above techniques. I <strike>have the feeling</strike> do not know if this is easier than discrete logarithm modulo $p$ even in the harder cases, like $n\cdot k=(p-1)$ with $k\approx\sqrt{p-1}$, and $p$,$k$,$n$ are primes.

Answer (score 6):

There are standard algorithms for this.  See, e.g., Section 7.3 of [Algorithmic Number Theory](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/ant.html) (Eric Bach, Jeffrey Shallit, MIT Press, 1996).

If you want to take square roots, you can use [Cipolla's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm), the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm), or [Pocklington's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington%27s_algorithm).  The Tonelli-Shanks algorithm apparently has a generalization to take arbitrary $n$th roots.

The GAP software can take $n$th roots modulo a prime (see [RootMod](http://www-gap.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Manuals/doc/ref/chap15.html#X7F9069D77AC48054)).

Here are some academic papers that also describe algorithms for solving this problem:

- [On Taking Roots in Finite Fields](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/AMM77.pdf).  Leonard Adleman, Kenneth Manders, Gary Miller.  FOCS 1977.
- [Efficient Computation of Roots in Finite Fields](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/roots.pdf).  Paulo Barreto, Jose Voloch.  Designs, Codes and Cryptography.

These algorithms are computationally efficient if $n$ is small.

I don't know if there are any algorithms that are computationally efficient if $n$ is large (i.e., that work for arbitrary $n$).  It's a good question!

Comment: Do you know the asymptotic cost of these algorithms w.r.t. to the exponent, in the worst case?

Comment: @fgrieu, good question. Actually, now that I take another look at those two papers, the running time seems to be linear in $n$, whereas we'd really want a running time that is poly($\log n$).  I don't know whether there are efficient algorithms for large $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. There is a polynomial algorithm for solving general polynomial equations, like $x^n - a \mod{p}$ in a finite field. And for simple powers, its even easier. So I wouldn't use this for a crypto system. Note that even square roots modulo a composite number *is* hard.

Comment: Can you be more precise? I couldn’t find an efficient algorithm to compute roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if  computing discrete logarithms there is hard.

Comment: @fgrieu: Sorry for the late response and thank you again. If you’re referring to this (a new version) http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4877.pdf (although I haven’t thoroughly read it) see for example that in pg7 last line you’ll have to compute a discrete algorithm or pg8 step 4 of the algorithm which in our case is infeasible.

Comment: In the question as I read it, it is wanted an algorithm polynomial in $\log p$ _and_ $\log n$. Is that the case for the unstated "polynomial algorithm for solving general polynomial equations" you are thinking of? I'm afraid that the algorithm outlined in section 4 [here](http://www.math.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/II/15pt6.pdf) might be polynomial in $n⋅\log p$. Indeed, for simple powers, there are faster options, like [Adleman-Manders-Miller](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/AMM77.pdf) but that seems polynomial in $\log p$ for fixed $n$ (notice the step "we factor gcd(n,p−1)").

Comment: Cantor-Zassenhaus or Berlekamp algorithms will factor polynomials, e.g.

Comment: Both algorithms have cost polynomial w.r.t. $\log p$, but at least polynomial w.r.t. $n$ (not $\log n$). In the context of the question, we'd like an algorithm polynomial w.r.t. $n$, if there is one (that's to find _one_ solution; enumerating _all_ the solutions has cost at least linear with the number of solutions, which can be $n$).